# image button doesnt fire jQuery / postback after first postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got an asp.net web app that has an update panel.
Inside of the update panel I have a grid view control.
In the grid view control I have two buttons notice the visibility:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:ImageButton class="DeleteLineItem" style="display:none;" ID="ibDelete2" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteRow" ImageUrl="images/d.gif" ToolTip="Delete Line Item?" />
  <asp:ImageButton class="TempDeleteLineItem" ID="ibTempDelete" OnClientClick="return false;" runat="server" ToolTip="Delete Line Item?" ImageUrl="images/d.gif" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Notice the first ones display is set to `none` the reason I do this is you will notice the second one has an onclientclick="return false;".  When I click the button with id ibTempDelete it calls some jquery to remove a row from my gridview and then it triggers the click event of the `ibDelete2` button (the one that's hidden).  The jquery for that is here:

```
$(".TempDeleteLineItem").click(function() { 
    $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut(3000, function() { 
        alert('hi');
        __doPostBack($(this).closest ('tr').find ('.DeleteLineItem').attr('name'), "");
        $(this).remove();
    }); 
});
```

I find the row and fade it out, do a post back by calling the DeleteLineItem event and removing the row.  Now when I first load my web page (assume there are 3 records in the grid view).  When my page loads I can easily click the `ibTempDelete` button and it calls the jquery, fades out the row, alerts hi, does the post back and removes the row...it works basically!  Great so what is my problem?

My problem is immediately after this post back (now I have 2 rows in my gridview) if I try to click the `ibTempDelete` button nothing happens, it appears it is no longer clickable?  The alert doesnt even display.

So my question is my lack of understanding on how asp.net and postbacks work.  As soon as I hit the first postback why is the button no longer clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shankar helped me in the chat, we ended up doing this:

```
$(".TempDeleteLineItem").live('click', function() { 
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut(1000, function() { 
       $(this).hide();
       $this.prev('.DeleteLineItem').click();
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `__doPostBack` the page is anyways going to be refreshed why are you calling `$(this).remove()`. May be you can call it before calling `__doPostBack`. When the page is freshly loaded even after postback the event handlers should work as it is. Try this using live.

```
$(".TempDeleteLineItem").live('click', function() { 
    $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut(3000, function() { 
        $(this).hide().find('.DeleteLineItem').click();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Shankar - you are right abotu the remove its unnecessary, this again is halfway working correctly.  The issue is I cannot seem to understand a strange issue I am having when I create new rows / delete all rows from the gridview.  The system becomes non-responsive due to this jquery / the postback via the client.  Is it possible we can talk in chat so I can discuss the issue with you?

Comment: @All - see my answer for the real answer but I had to give ShankarSangoli credit as he is the one who came up with it and helped me.  Thanks ShankarSangoli